# What does a nullable future mean as return type in async function?

Tags: flutter, dart

```dart
Future<String?>? returnStringOrNull() async 
{
  return Random().nextBool() ? "OK" : null;
}
```

In the above flutter code why is the return type  `Future<String?>?` and not `Future<String?>`

This return type is generated by using `Add return type` quick fix in both vscode and android studio.

From what I understand, async functions always return a Future. `Future<String?>?` would mean that the above function can return a null instead of a Future, which in my opinion should not be possible.

Comment: In general, I'd say that it means that the author of the code doesn't know what they're doing.  If Dart extensions are adding `Future<T>?` return types to `async` functions automatically, it sounds like a bug that you should report.

Comment: @jamesdlin Thanks. I have posted an issue on dart-lang sdk as the issue is reproducible on all IDEs.

Answer (score -1):

in Dart, the ? after `Future<T?>` is not needed if the return type of the method is already specified as `Future<T?>`.

In your case, `Future<String?>` would be sufficient to indicate that the method returns a future that resolves to either a String or null. The extra `?` after `Future<String?>` doesn't add any additional meaning and is therefore not necessary.

Answer (score -3):

In theory, `Future<String?>? returnStringOrNull()  ...`

stand for return a future or null and the future is a String or null.

I you take a look of what the function do, there is no need of using a future.

Everything that this function do is returning a string or null.

So the function should be:

```
String? returnStringOrNull() 
{
  return Random().nextBool() ? "OK" : null;
}
```

no need to Future here.

Comment: An `async` function *must* return either a `Future` or `void`.  A return type of `String?` in your example is not legal.

Comment: @jamesdlin Just an typo from copy/paste of the original question.

If youn have readthe text before the code you will have understand that!

Comment: But that's not what the OP is asking about.

Comment: Ok, but why returning a future when it is not necessary? `Random().nextBool() ? "OK" : null;` definitively not returning a Future! So no need to be async and no need to return a Future!

Comment: That's just a non-ideal example.  It's not the point of the OP's question.

Comment: @jamesdlin
So, in your opinion, only the answer to the question matters? Pointing out an erroneous usage is not legal because it is not part of the question?
So, people who visit this post will see code that returns a Future while the function code is not asynchronous and that doesn't bother you?
Me yes!

Comment: @jamesdlin
Am I to understand that your silence is acquiescence?

Comment: No.  It depends on the situation.  In some cases, the asker is clueless and should be asking a different question to solve their problem.  In *this case*, it's abundantly clear that the question is why the Dart IDE extension is suggesting `Future<T?>?` at all, which is *wrong* regardless of the example used.  If you answered by saying something like, "`Future<T?>?` is wrong and never necessary; the IDE extension should not be doing that.  However, your particular example does not need to return a `Future` at all...", then that would be fine.

Comment: @jamesdlin
Are you sure you read what I write correctly? Maybe my English isn't clear enough?
In my answer this is definitely not an example.
The author of the question shows an example of his code and explains that VS code indicates an error correction. Either! But the author's code ABSOLUTELY does not require returning a Future!!!
This is what I am desperately trying to explain. Not saying it could lead visitors to this post to think that it is normal to return a Future when no asynchronous code is present in the body of the function.
Isn't what I'm saying true?
...

Comment: ...
So not saying it amounts to letting potentials readers think wrong things!!!

Comment: You are right that returning the `Future` is not necessary; that was never being disputed.  However, it does not answer the question about the incorrect return type.  As I said, dissecting the example is fine if *you also answer the question*.  I am repeating myself and don't wish to continue fruitless arguing.  If I don't reply, that does not imply agreement.